# How to show button on div mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i want to show button on div hover.
when i hover mouse on div then button show otherwise hide.

my button in `divbutton` div.

html

```
<div class="divbutton">
   <button type="button" style="display: none;">Hello</button>
</div>
```

when I hover mouse on div it should show but how to do that i do not know.
when I remove mouse button again hide.
Thank you.

Comment: I've retagged your question using CSS, assuming that you are OBVIOUSLY open to CSS solutions, if not than you can simply revert back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use following jQuery to perform your task.

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/FWG8R/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.divbutton', function () {
        $(this).find(":button").show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.divbutton', function () {
        $(this).find(":button").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: No `jQuery` tag with this question

Comment: Yes I know but this is easy way and I have done something like this.

Comment: Thanks helped me ;)

Comment: Why `':button'` and not `'button'`?

Answer (score 40):

Use the below selector

```
button {
  display: none; /* Hide button */
}

.divbutton:hover button {
   display: block; /* On :hover of div show button */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5Gcc/)

Also make sure you assign some `height` or `min-height` to your `div` element, else it will be `0` as it doesn't hold any content. Also, don't use `display: none;` as inline style, as inline styles have highest specificity, and hence, you will be forced to use `!important` which is bad.

In the above example am using `button {/*Styles*/}` but that is a general element selector, so make sure you define a `class` to your `button` element.

Comment: Good answer. CSS works even if the user does not allow scripts on his browser.

Comment: If you want the button to disappear without affecting the flow or positions of other elements, try using `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` instead of `display`.

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Alien's answer gives a nice CSS implementation. If you need in jquery, use this -

```
$( ".divbutton" )
 .on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("button").show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("button").hide();
});
```

In pure JavaScript -

```
var buttonDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("divbutton")[0];  //better use some id and then use getElementById

buttonDiv.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("YourButtonId").style.display = 'block';
}

buttonDiv.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById("YourButtonId").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('.divbutton').mouseover(function(event)
{
   $(this).find('button').show();
});

$('.divbutton').mouseout(function(event)
{
   $(this).find('button').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first hide the button with transform property.

```
button{
transform:translate(100%,100%)
//this will move the button right and buttom
}
```

then when you hover on div, you bring it back

```
.divbutton:hover button{
     //class name should have been divButton
     transform:translate(0,0)}
```