# Showing button on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like this

```
<tbody id="addNew">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="padding:6px 0 0 0;"><b>Any Other Comments ?</b><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right hide" id="hover12" style="display: inline;"></i></td>
      <td>

      </td>
      <td width="35%" style="padding:10px 0 0 0;" class="Fsize12 out" id="a12"></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

There is a bootstrap icon which is hidden at the loading of the page.When I hover on the `TD` then I only I want the button to show and upon mouse Leave I want it to hide again.

So I did like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#addNew').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').show();
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
               $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

But it does not work.I mean on mouse over the button remains hidden and does not show up.Can any body please point out the mistake I have done

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/B4CU9/1/

Comment: @Barmar but why for me it does not work?

Comment: You must be doing something different from what you posted. Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem? Or post a link to the site where it fails?

Comment: @Barmar I run it in my local system.If you want then I can show the full code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show button on div mouse hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563803/how-to-show-button-on-div-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you are using Bootstrap. The problem here is that `hide` class has higher priority due to `!important` keyword. That's why you can't show it by simply adding inline `display: inline` styles (by using `.show` method). Instead you can toggle `hide` class, it will also make your code shorter:

```
$('#addNew').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

You can also go with separate `removeClass('hide')` and `addClass('hide')` of course:

```
$('#addNew').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('hide');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('.glyphicon').addClass('hide');
    }
}, 'tr');
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/m0hfHYy4LdBp7hjJd59U?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.Your way works but the problem it shows all the hidden buttons of all the tds even if I simply mouse over on a single td.http://plnkr.co/edit/GpxZZLgjc4RhBYxUfZIc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the class `.hide`. You must toggle it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#addNew').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').show();
            $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').hide();
            $(this).children().find('.glyphicon').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

You may want to [check fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/b4JAJ/)