# How to appear an Image in specific location through hover on link? (HTML/CSS3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make an image appear in a specific place (ex. customized image box) through hovering a link. Here is my code, but it is not working the way I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
a #link1:hover{
    content: url("winter.jpg");
}
a #link2:hover{
    content: url("sunset.jpg");
}
a #link3:hover{
    content: url("Blue hills.jpg");
}
</style>

<body>
<a href=""><div id="link1">Link1</div></a>
<a href=""><div id="link2">Link2</div></a>
<a href=""><div id="link3">Link3</div></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is an illustration for easy realization of my idea:

[image: image description]

Comment: I'm sorry, but "but it is not working the way I want" is not a helpful problem statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show button on div mouse hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563803/how-to-show-button-on-div-mouse-hover)

Comment: Yes, i've tried googling but i'm afraid that i can't find the appropriate answer for my idea. I hope someone can help me. :(

Comment: The css rule 'content' only works with :before and :after pseudos. Try background-image instead.

Comment: similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563803/how-to-show-button-on-div-mouse-hover

Comment: try [Google](http://www.google.com) it got the best answers for simple things like this

Answer (score 0):

Try to google this first. Should be able to find pretty easy. But it should be something like this.

## HTML

```
<img class="1" src="winter.jpg">
<img class="2" src="sunset.jpg">
<img class="3" src="Blue Hills.jpg">
```

## CSS

```
.1 .2 .3{
     -code the position here-
     display: none;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link1").mouseenter(function(){
        $("1").show();
    });
    $("#link2").mouseenter(function(){
        $("2").show();
    });
    $("#link3").mouseenter(function(){
        $("3").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are several approaches to this but the first one that comes to mind is create an array of your image paths. Then (a little longwinded but) if you just want something to work straight away you could try just putting a function on each links hover state to change the image path of the current image in that custom div you show. Something like this:

```
<style>
.customBox{
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}
.customBox img{
 max-height: 300px;
 max-width: 300px;
}
</style>

<a href=""><div id="link1">Link1</div></a>
<a href=""><div id="link2">Link2</div></a>
<a href=""><div id="link3">Link3</div></a>
<div class="customBox"><img src=""></div>

<script>
var images = ['https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/winter-wallpaper-12.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Anatomy_of_a_Sunset-2.jpg','http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/asia/in/blue-hills-0.jpg'];

$('#link1').hover(function(){
$('.customBox img').attr('src', images[0]);
});

$('#link2').hover(function(){
$('.customBox img').attr('src', images[1]);
})

$('#link3').hover(function(){
$('.customBox img').attr('src', images[2]);
})
</script>

http://codepen.io/tomdreamevil/pen/XjPoVp?editors=1111
```

Comment: obviously remove the image url's in the array with your winter.jpg, sunset.jpg and blue hills.jpg :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript ...

```js
window.addEventListener("load", hoverChangeImageEffect); 
 
 function hoverChangeImageEffect() {
 
  var imageHolder = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("setImage");
 
  for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) hoverChangeImage(links[i]);
  
  function hoverChangeImage(link) {
   link.onmouseover = function linkHover() {
    imageHolder.src = link.getAttribute("image");
   }
  }
 }
```

```css
img.imageHolder {
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

ul.links {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover the mouse over the links:</p>

<ul class="links">
 <li><a href="" class="setImage" image="http://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/img/jobs/ico-dismiss.svg">Anchor text1</a></li>
 <li><a href="" class="setImage" image="http://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/img/jobs/ico-location-gray.svg">Anchor text2</a></li>
 <li><a href="" class="setImage" image="http://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/img/jobs/ico-visa-pink.svg">Anchor text3</a></li>
</ul>

<img id="imageHolder" class="imageHolder" src="" height="100">
```