# How can I stack divs in a relative parent div and reveal the bottom div on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm working on a project where there is a sidebar with three squares in it. The squares will have a sub-section title, and when hovering I want to reveal a description. The sidebar is relative because there is another div to the right side of it. So far the boxes are all stacking on each other and hover does nothing, I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm open to CSS or JS solutions.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.boxes {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: #C4D5E4;
  margin: 10%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.boxes a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.boxesHover {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: #6BA5CD;
  margin: 10%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.boxesHover:hover .boxesHover {
  z-index: 2;
}

.boxesHover a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

I'm working on a project where there is a sidebar with three squares in it. The squares will have a sub-section title, and when hovering I want to reveal a description. The sidebar is relative because there is another div to the right side of it. So far the boxes are all stacking on each other and hover does nothing, I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm open to CSS or JS solutions.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

  <div class="boxes">
    <a href="">Audience</a>
  </div>
  <div class="boxesHover">
    <ul>
      <li>Description 1</li>
      <li>Description 2</li>
      <li>Description 3</li>
      <li>Description 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes">
    <a href="">Methods</a>
  </div>

  <div class="boxesHover">
    <ul>
      <li>Description 1</li>
      <li>Description 2</li>
      <li>Description 3</li>
      <li>Description 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes">
    <a href="">Industry</a>
  </div>

  <div class="boxesHover">
    <ul>
      <li>Description 1</li>
      <li>Description 2</li>
      <li>Description 3</li>
      <li>Description 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi have a look here it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563803/how-to-show-button-on-div-mouse-hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are putting the hover feature on the div, not on the actual boxes.

Try this:

```
<div>
<ul href="">
  <li class="boxesHover">Diversification</li>
  <li class="boxesHover">Musical Chairs</li>
  <li class="boxesHover">Telecome M&A</li>
  <li class="boxesHover">Fake News</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this :) unfortunately, I think I may not have described it properly. The ul are the descriptions that I want in "boxHover". "boxes" should show when the user isn't hovering. When the user hovers over "boxes" I want "boxesHover" to show over "boxes" with the ul as the text

Comment: I'm trying to make three boxes in a row, vertically, with 10% space in between. When hovering over an individual box I want a different box to appear and cover the original box with the ul content and different background color.

Comment: I fixed the hover issue, but the three boxes still aren't lining up correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with some help from my professor, he suggested a flex box. Code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">

<div class="boxes">
    <a href="audience.html">
        <p>Audience</p>
        <ul class="boxeshover">
          <li>Subscriptions</li>
          <li>Membership</li>
          <li>Global Footprint</li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes">
    <a href="methods.html">
      <p>Methods</p>
      <ul class="boxeshover">
        <li>Profitability</li>
        <li>Data Practices</li>
        <li>Metrics of Success</li>
        <li>E-Commerce</li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </div>

    <div class="boxes">
      <a href="industry.html">
        <p>Industry</p>
        <ul class="boxeshover">
          <li>Diversification</li>
          <li>Musical Chairs</li>
          <li>Telecom M&A</li>
          <li>Fake News</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#CDCDCD;
  margin: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.boxes a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.boxeshover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#C05746;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 175%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.boxes:hover .boxeshover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```